# C# Equals Statement Returning False

Tags: c#, loops, random, foreach, equals

My equals if statements keep returning false of the letter guesses is not the first letter, does anyone have any idea why this may be? I've debugged a lot that's how I found out it returns a false boolean statement. I've googled a lot but I have found no enlightenment. The first two if statements return true if the answer is the correct lengh

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Guess_The_Word
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private int wrongGuesses = 0;
        private int userGuesses;
        private int score = 0;
        private string secretWord = String.Empty;
        private string[] words;
        private string currentWord = string.Empty;
        private string userGuess = string.Empty;
        private string userInput = string.Empty;
        private string randomInput = string.Empty;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



        }

        private void guessBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            char[] userInputArray = userInputBox.Text.ToLowerInvariant().ToCharArray();
            char[] currentWordCharArray = currentWord.ToLowerInvariant().ToCharArray();
            //Assume that userInput would never be superior than randomCharArray
            //And contain only one char
            for (int i = 0; i < currentWordCharArray.Length; i++)
            {
                if (userInputArray.Length > 0 && userInputArray.Length > i)
                    if (currentWordCharArray.Length > 0 && currentWordCharArray.Length > i)
                        if (userInputArray[0].Equals(currentWordCharArray[i]))

                {
                    UpdateScore();
                }
            }
            // Clean userInput in form
            userInputBox.Text = string.Empty;

        }


        private void resetGamebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetUpWords();


        }

        private void SetUpWords()
        {
            string path = (@"C:\commonwords.txt"); // Save the variable path with the path to the txt file
            words = File.ReadAllLines(path);
            int guessIndex = (new Random()).Next(words.Length);
            currentWord = words[guessIndex];
            wordlbl.Text = string.Empty;
            for (int i = 0; i < currentWord.Length; i++)
            {

                wordlbl.Text += "*";

            }
        }

        private void userInputBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void UpdateScore()
        {
            score++;
            scorelbl.Text = Convert.ToString(score);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You're not assigning `rand.Next()` result to the array's elements.

Comment: `rand.Next(Min, Max)` returns a value - you need to add it to your array

Comment: Did any of the answers help @LiamVallance ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you didn't initialize your array with random numbers.
change

```
foreach (int value in randomArray)
    {
        rand.Next(Min, Max);
    }
```

to

```
for (var i=0; i < randomArray.Length; i++) {
    randomArray[i] = rand.Next(Min, Max);
}
```

Comment: OP did initialize array, but did not populate it ;) In addition this won't work as you cannot modify the collection as you iterate it

Comment: Thank you! I've just got back to learning and started to learn arrays.. I wonder is there a better wayto fill the txtboxes?

Answer (score 6):

You have to *save* values generated, put `for` loop instead `foreach`:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < randomArray.Length; ++i)
    randomArray[i] = rand.Next(Min, Max);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (int value in randomArray)
{
    rand.Next(Min, Max);
}
```

is not doing what you think it does.

It is not **setting** the values there, it is just iterating over the array and generating some random numbers (and throwing them away since you aren't assigning `rand.Next` to anything).

You need to replace it with:

```
for (var i=0; i < randomArray.Length; i++)
{
    randomArray[i] = rand.Next(Min, Max);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is because you are not assigning `rand.Next()` to any value. Change your `foreach` loop to this `for` loop instead:

```
for (int i=0;i<6;i++)
{
    randomArray[i] = rand.Next(Min, Max);
}
```

What your current code does is iterate through each element in your array (6 in this case), calls `rand.Next()`, but never assigns it to any element.